# Grandpa and Grandson together again

Tags: riddle, tefilla, names, family-members

What are the names of TWO distinct grandfathers and their grandsons are mentioned in the weekday Shemoneh Esrei ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Eloke avraham eloke yitzchak veloke yaakov* and *ata chonen l'adam daas umlamed leenosh bina*.

Comment: Brilliant! I was totally stumped.

Comment: @SethJ, the brilliance isn't mine: I'd heard the question and this answer before.