# Where in davening is a grandfather and his grandson mentioned without the father?

Tags: tefilla, riddle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grandpa and Grandson together again](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/grandpa-and-grandson-together-again)

Where in davening is a grandfather and his grandson mentioned without the father? Iv'e searched most of the weekday davening and found nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In Shemonah Esrei we say: Attah chonein l'adam daas, u'melamed l'enosh binah.

Adam was the father of Shes, who was the father of Enosh, thus making Adam Enosh's grandfather. The translation of this sentence does not literally make the words adam and enosh mean Adam and Enosh, but this is the answer to the riddle.